# Java Arabic string date parse to date object

Tags: java, string, date, object, arabic

Can you please let me know how we can parse arabic date in String format as shown below to date object:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofpattern("yyyy dd MMMM",locale).format(islamicDate));
```

Now got arabic date in String Format as:

**1437 06 Rajab**

Now got arabic date in String Format as:

*How to convert/parse above string to date object?*

```
String xyz=DateTimeFormatter.ofpattern("yyyy dd MMMM",locale).format(islamicDate));
// now use xyz string to get hijiri date object
```

On **Thu, Feb 16, 2017 at 1:48 PM**, **Sajid Ahmed**  wrote:

```
public class HijriDate {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      HijrahDate date1 = HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.dateNow();
      System.out.println("HijrahDate date :: "+date1);
      System.out.println("hijri to gregorian from sysdate   :: "+IsoChronology.INSTANCE.date(date1).toString());

      HijrahDate hd1 = HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(1438,04,18);
      System.out.println("hijri to gregorian using islamic year month day ( 1 way ):: "+IsoChronology.INSTANCE.date(hd1));
      System.out.println("hijri to gregorian using islamic year month day using localDate( 2 way ):: "+LocalDate.from(hd1));

      Date date=new java.util.Date();
      Calendar cl=Calendar.getInstance();
      cl.setTime(date);
      System.out.println("Normal gregorian Date1 :: "+date);
      cl.add(Calendar.DATE,1);               
      HijrahDate islamyDate = HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(LocalDate.of(cl.get(Calendar.YEAR),cl.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cl.get(Calendar.DATE)));
      System.out.println("gregorian to hijri one day plus  :: " + islamyDate.toString());

      //HijrahDate hd = HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(LocalDate.of(2017,01, 16));
      System.out.println("format date MMMM  :: "+DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM").format(islamyDate));
      System.out.println("format date MMMM  dd-MMMM-yyyy  :: "+DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMMM-yyyy").format(islamyDate));

      //HijrahDate hd1 = HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(LocalDate.of(2017,01, 16));
      //Locale locale = new Locale("ar","SA");
      Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguageTag("ar-SA-u-nu-arab").build();
      System.out.println("format dd-MMMM-yyyy :: "+DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMMM-yyyy", locale).format(islamyDate));

      String dop = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE , dd  MMMM ,yyyy", locale).format(islamyDate);    
      System.out.println("format 'EEEE , dd  MMMM ,yyyy' with number format with out number format with locale :: "+dop);    
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code above doesn't compile, and it's incomplete. It doesn't show how you defined `locale` and `islamicDate` and you misspelled `ofpattern` and have a closing `)` too many. The solution is as simple as replacing `format` with `parse` but I can't verify since you haven't provided working code above.

Comment: Plz check above code i need to take hijiri date as string and convert it into hijiri date object

Comment: If it's in digits i can easily covert it in hijiridate like below HijrahDate d=HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(1437,07,06);  but i have string date i.e 1437 06 Rajab now i hv to create date object from this

Comment: Maybe https://www.irif.fr/~yunes/cours/annexes/java/docs/tutorial/datetime/iso/nonIso.html

Comment: Again in above link hijrah string date  month is in digits System.out.printf("%s%n", StringConverter.fromString("6/16/1417 1",     HijrahChronology.INSTANCE)); In my case month name  is Rajab not 07 digit